# Adding a variable to a dataset if it doesn't exist

Tags: r, variables

Working in R, I need to add a column of zeros for missing days - if there are any.

I'm dealing with a number of datasets which contain dates. I find the day for each date (day.received) and then use:

```
dcast(data, ... ~ day.received)
```

This turns my days into columns and gives counts for the number of records that apply. Perfect!

However, I just found out that if I don't have any records for a day, I don't get a column created when I dcast. That makes my code throw errors all over the place since my dataframe is no longer the expected length and any references to the column for the missing day are not found.

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(42)
days <- factor(c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday'),
           c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday'))
data <- data.frame(Place = sample(c('A','B','C'),replace = TRUE, 50), 
       day.received = sample(days, 50, replace=TRUE))
data$day.received[data$day.received == 'Friday'] <- "Saturday"
data <- dcast(data, ... ~ day.received)
data
```

Obviously I can use %in% to find whether Monday to Sunday are in the colnames, but how do I use that information to add a column of zeros for the missing day? I can calculate the length of the vector I need to add, let's say it's 10.

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's hard to say, but using factors might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually just missing the `drop` argument:

```
dcast(data, ... ~ day.received, drop = FALSE)
# Using day.received as value column: use value.var to override.
# Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
#   Place Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
# 1     A      2       4         1        1      0        2      0
# 2     B      3       2         2        2      0        7      1
# 3     C      3       4         4        3      0        7      2
```

Answer (score 3):

Not completely sure what you need as there isn't a clear example, but are you looking for something like:

```
days <- days.of.week <- weekdays(x=as.Date(seq(7), origin="1950-01-01"))
days

## [1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"   

set.seed(1492) # make reproducible

# fabricated data frame with missing weekdays

data <- data.frame(
  Sunday=sample(1:100, 10),
  Tuesday=sample(1:100, 10),
  Thursday=sample(1:100, 10))

head(data, 3)

##   Sunday Tuesday Thursday
## 1     28      65       64
## 2     22      64       38
## 3     19      20       13

# fill in missing columns

data[, setdiff(days, colnames(data))] <- 0
head(data, 3)

##    Sunday Tuesday Thursday Monday Wednesday Friday Saturday
## 1      28      65       64      0         0      0        0
## 2      22      64       38      0         0      0        0
## 3      19      20       13      0         0      0        0
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you could add columns in that manner. That is just the problem I was trying to solve, sorry for making you do it blind, but you nailed it.